# How to changed a vector of strings into variables with + signs inbetween

Tags: r

I have a group like so

```
group=c("year","reach", "treatment.long", "transect")
```

then later in my code I need to `dcast()` my data based on the `group` (note the group will be changing).

```
dcast(melted.data, year + reach + treatment.long + transect ~ stat, value.var="value")
```

How can I get the `group` into the format `year + reach + treatment.long + transect`?

Thank you

I adjusted it to

dcast(melted.data, as.formula(paste(paste( group, collapse=' + ' ), "~ stat")), value.var="value")

and am getting the error "Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `paste` with the `collapse` argument:

paste( group, collapse=' + ' )

This will create the string.  You can copy and paste it to the command line in the middle of the command, or you can also use paste to add the `~ stat` and pass the resulting string through `as.formula`.  See the `?as.formula` help page.

Comment: That is helpful but now i am getting the error
Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
Any ideas?

Comment: Post the actual code as an edit to your question. Snow's answer looks like it would work, but you may have mangled some step or another.

Comment: I fixed it, I am not sure how but I did.